# $(p, \theta)$ values of lines intersecting the line segment from $(-l/2,0)$ to $(l/2, 0)$

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to argue that any line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that intersects the line segment $L$ along the $x$-axis from $- \frac{l}{2}$ to $\frac{l}{2}$, for some $l >0$, must make angle with the $x$ axis in the range $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ and have distance from the origin, say $p$, in the range $[0, |\cos(\theta)|*l/2 ]$.

The first part is easy sin.c any line segment through the origin that makes angle $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi]$ with the $x$-axis will intersect $L.$

To show the range of $p,$ it seems to me that a vertical line at $x=l/2$ has distance $l/2$ from the origin and intersect $L$ with $\theta = \pi/2,$ while a vertical line at $x=0$ intersects $L$ and has distance $0$ from the origin. I am not sure why the max value for $p$ should be $l/2.$ Any insights appreciated.

The context of this question, for reference, is in an integral in Do Carmo's *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* at the bottom of page $44$ as part of an argument for the Cauchy-Crofton formula.

Comment: The distance should have been in the range $ \left(0, \frac{l \sin\theta}{2} \right)$.

Comment: @MathLover edit added original use of range for $p$.

Comment: The angle between a vertical line and the $x$-axis is $\pi /2,$ it is not $0.$

Comment: @user376343 fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof (almost) without words.

The given line intersects the $x$-axis at a point $A.$ The blue and brown triangles are similar.
Hence $$p\leq \frac{l}{2}\sin\theta,$$ where $p$ and $\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta$ are the lenghts of corresponding sides opposite to the angle $\theta.$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $r \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Let $A$ be the intersection of the line perpendicular to $r$ that goes through the origin with $r$, so that $p = d(A,O)$. Let $B$ be the intersection of $r$ with the x-axis, with $B=(x_B,0)$.

Consider first the case $\theta \neq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then the triangle $[AOB]$ is a right triangle. Drawing this picture we can see that $p = x_B \lvert \sin (\theta) \rvert$. Then $\lvert x_B \rvert \leq \frac{l}{2}$ implies that $p \leq \frac{l}{2} \lvert \sin(\theta) \rvert$.

Now, if $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ it is also correct because we know that the range should be $p \in [0,\frac{l}{2}]$ which agrees with the formula.

Comment: I don't understand, to measure the distance between some line $r$ and the origin, you can take the line through the origin that is perpendicular to $r$, so for that reason I think $[AOB]$ is always a right angled triangle.

Comment: Right sorry, my mistake I goofed on that one.